# Why is my PDO::FETCH Statement Returning 0?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my code below:

```
$barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$movietitle = $_POST['movietitle'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(movietitle) FROM movies WHERE movietitle LIKE '%:movie%'");
$stmt->bindParam(':movie', $movietitle);
$stmt->execute();
$fetch = $stmt->fetch();
if($fetch[0] == 0) {    
    $displaytitle = $_POST['displaytitle'];
    $media = $_POST['media'];
    $youtube = $_POST['youtube'];
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];
    $youtube = "www.youtube.com/embed/" . $youtube;
    $stmtins = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `movies` VALUES (null, :genre, :movietitle, :displaytitle, :year, :youtube, :media, :barcode)");
    $stmtins->bindParam(':genre', $genre);
    $stmtins->bindParam(':movietitle', $movietitle);
    $stmtins->bindParam(':displaytitle', $displaytitle);
    $stmtins->bindParam(':year', $year);
    $stmtins->bindParam(':youtube', $youtube);
    $stmtins->bindParam(':media', $media);
    $stmtins->bindParam(':barcode', $barcode);
    $stmtins->execute();
    $message = "The movie was added to your database. - $fetch[0]";
} else {
    $message = "Already owned.";
}
```

Every time it's run, $fetch[0] ALWAYS returns 0, despite the $stmt query returning more than 0. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you run PDO in exception mode...

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then you would see the query error.

The problem is, you can't use interpolate params like you have in your `LIKE` comparison. Try this instead...

```
"SELECT COUNT(movietitle) FROM movies WHERE movietitle LIKE CONCAT('%', :movie, '%')"
```

There's also an easier way to check for existence...

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM movies WHERE movietitle LIKE CONCAT('%', :movie, '%')");
$stmt->bindParam(':movie', $movietitle);
$stmt->execute();
if(!$stmt->fetch()) {
    // fetch will return false if there are no rows
```

Comment: Cheers! I could have sworn I've done it this way before. Either way, thanks!